# Can you merge the results of a Union query with the SUM of another column?

Tags: php, mysql

Would this statement work fine even though the `Quantity` column is `decimal(10,4)` while the `price` column is `decimal(8,2)`?

```
"(SELECT `price` FROM `"
.$this->symbol."Trades` ORDER BY `TS` DESC LIMIT 1) UNION (SELECT "
."`price` FROM `".$this->symbol."Trades` WHERE `TS` >="
." DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY) ORDER BY `TS` ASC LIMIT 1) UNION"
." (SELECT SUM(`Quantity`) AS volume FROM `".
$this->symbol."Trades` WHERE `TS` >= DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 1 DAY))"
```

Comment: yes it will. but the query itself is  weird too much! :-)

Comment: Can you think of a better way to select the price 24 hours ago, the newest price, and the volume in a single query? @Alex

Comment: yes I can. but you didn't ask for that, you did ask some simple question about weird query. And at least it should not be `UNION` but `JOIIN ... ON 1` to get 3 columns but not 3 records

Comment: Please see my new question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34001883/is-there-a-better-way-to-select-the-row-closest-to-24-hours-ago-the-last-insert @Alex